# How to render html on ios fcm push notification

Tags: reactjs, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, cordova-plugin-fcm

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBXir.jpg) How to render as rich text.

im try to convet aps.alert.body as NSAttributeString but not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe you can share what steps have you done and what specific blocker are you experiencing. If you can include the code that you've tried, others can easily help you debug it. You can read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).